# Is js guaranteed to check the length of the array over the course of a for-of loop?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I like to use this kind of pattern for flattening nested data (arrays, tree structures and the like)

```
const stuff = [1, [2, [3, 4]]];
let pile = [stuff];
for (let item of pile) {
    if (item instanceof Array) pile.push(...item);
    else console.log(item);
}
```

It occurred to me though that I'm just assuming that

```
for (let item of pile) { ...
```

is syntax candy for

```
for (let i = 0; i < pile.length; i++) { const item = pile[i]; ...
```

while it could also be syntax candy for

```
for (let i = 0, length = pile.length; i < length; i++) { const item = pile[i]; ...
```

Right now it works the way I expect but is it guaranteed to work or is it implementation specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-Of Loop vs. For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924958/for-of-loop-vs-for-loop)

Comment: For-of is NOT syntactic-sugar of the indexed version. There are iterators and generators involved: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: @Phil the example code does exactly that, doesn't mean its guaranteed behavior however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> In general, it is best not to add, modify, or remove properties from
> the object during iteration, other than the property currently being
> visited. There is no guarantee whether an added property will be
> visited, whether a modified property (other than the current one) will
> be visited before or after it is modified, or whether a deleted
> property will be visited before it is deleted.

This suggests it is syntactic sugar for

```js
for (let i = 0, length = pile.length; i < length; i++) { const item = pile[i]; ...
```

Or something that is similar to that.